# Why C does not have a correct implementation of implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, c, implicit-conversion

The following code prints 99 where 'c' was converted implicitly to 99.

```
printf("%d", 'c');
```

But the following code prints 0.000000:

```
printf("%f", 23);
```

Why in the second case was the integer 23 not converted into 23.00000 as was in the first case? Does this reflect poor implementation of implicit conversion in C? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If there is no promotion possible from int to float as one of the answer suggests, then why is there a promotion of int to float when we write

```
float x = 23;
```

Why so?

Comment: `c` wasn't implicitly converted to 99; [it **is** 99](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii). As to the latter, how exactly would you expect `printf` in C to know you *didn't* pass it a `float`?

Comment: The compiler cannot guess what you want to push into the stack when you call `printf`, because it is a variadic function (takes an unknown number of arguments whose types are unknown except for the first). So it promotes (cast) every integer type with size less than `int` (such as `char` and `short`) to `int`, and every non-integer type with size less than `double` (such a `float`) to `double`. That is why your second example yields the wrong output. The compiler pushes `23` as `int` (4 bytes on most platforms), but `printf` expects a `double` (8 bytes on most platforms).

Comment: @coder12345: No answer says that conversion from int to double is impossible; just that it doesn't happen to the arguments of variadic functions. To make it more obvious why not, imagine that the code were actually: `printf(format, 23);`. How does the compiler know that `format` is assigned (at run-time) to the value `"%f"`?

Comment: For the record, many compilers nowadays have extensions that perform analysis on variadic functions with a `const char *` argument called `fmt` and will type-check the arguments you're passing it to make sure they match up correctly with the format string literal.

Comment: @Qix: Yes, but they issue warnings, and they can only check format strings supplied as literals, which is in no way required. Regardless, no compiler inserts code to convert the types of printf arguments based on the format. (gcc, by the way, expects a pragma to tell it that a function is printf-like or scanf-like).

Comment: @rici of course; it would only warn you. Compilers rarely insert code for you, much less change the types of your arguments :)

Comment: @qix: but the compiler would insert code to convert an int argument to a double if there were a function prototype with a double parameter.

Comment: @rici promotion, though, is different than changing types. For all intents and purposes, variadic arguments are pretty much typeless. It's a property of variadic functions; there is no *type* to put on them.

Comment: `printf` was invented 40-something years ago. 40 years is really, really, REALLY old. That's why.

Comment: "Why C does not have a correct implementation of implicit conversion?" – that's plain nonsense. C is a language, not an implementation. Individual implementations (e.g. compilers) may or may implement C's implicit conversion rules either correctly or incorrectly. Your implementation happens to implement them **correctly,** but your code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Worth it to comment that this is one of the prime examples for using Variadic templates in C++11, which allow you to write a version of `printf` which adapts to whatever types you give it (and to know those types) rather than implicitly casting them

Answer (score 12):

In C, 'c' *is* an `int`. No conversion is performed.

Even if it were a `char` (as it is in C++), `char` is an integer type, and in the argument lists of variadic functions like `printf`, all variadic arguments undergo arithmetic promotion, which will automatically widen a `char` to an `int`, or a `float` to a `double` -- but not an `int` to a `double`.

Comment: but the promotion of int to a double does occur when we write int x = 2.33; why so??

Comment: @coder12345: That's the conversion of a double to an int, and it happens in the assignment operator, which knows the types of both operands. But the compiler does not know the "expected" type of an argument to a variadic function.

Comment: @coder12345 that isn't a promotion from `int` to `double`; it's a *demotion* from `double` to `int`. Nor is that the same as invoking a function with variadic parameters. A tighter example would be `void foo(float x){}` and invoking with `foo('c');`. The target type is known *at compile time*. (and uptick rici; nice answer)

Comment: In the special case of a variadic function, it is neither a promotion nor a demotion. It is a reinterpretation of the memory because variadic arguments are untyped.

Comment: @VoidStar do you know what my comment was responding to? Look at the OP's example in the first comment of this answer.

Comment: @VoidStar: "That" in the context of WhozCraig's comment refers to `int x = 2.33`, and that's a conversion. I wouldn't use the word "demotion" either, but it's a narrowing conversion, not a reinterpretation.

Comment: @rici Sorry I mean to ask why there is a  promotion of int to float when we write float x = 23;

Comment: @coder12345: Because that's the compiler recognizing the type difference correctly. As it normally does. But variadic functions like `printf` are a special case where the type system doesn't recognize that a float is being requested by the format specifier %f. Basically, the type system is "off" inside `printf`.

Answer (score 9):

`printf` is a variadic function, which means its arguments (apart from the first one) are effectively untyped by the time they are accessed. This rules out any kind of smart type conversion inside `printf`'s argument list (although there are certain [default conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) that take place, kind of blindly and irrespective of the format specifiers).

In the first example, 'c' is already an `int`. But in the case of the float, it is not performing the conversion necessary to turn an `int` into a `float` because the compiler doesn't know it should, or more precisely, according to the spec, there is nothing to do but believe the format specifier is the source of truth regarding the type. It believes the data to to already be a float because the format specifier `%f` is telling it so, and it cannot see the type of the 23 that is passed in.

This makes it very easy for the developer to accidentally cause a crash-- the developer has to make sure the format specifiers (e.g. %d) match up to the data supplied themselves. For example, mixing a "%s" specifier with an `int` input would cause a runtime crash because the compiler will simply "believe" the format specifier is not wrong. Even worse, try omitting the data entirely... `printf("%f %f %f")` will cause it to look for arguments that don't even exist, which will crash. Sadly the compiler must accept and build this crashing code.

If you care to see the conundrum more closely, google `va_list`/`va_start`/`va_stop`, which `printf` uses. Understand that this mechanism allows us to loop through the data sent into `printf`, but, the type information is lost. It is untyped binary data, and to use it, it uses the format specifier `%f` to realize that a float is even there. It then interprets the binary data as a `float` and writes it into the string before showing it.

Another angle to look at it from is that the compiler ignores string contents like `%f` in its type system... `%f`is compiled but it is applied only at runtime while running the function. But at runtime, all type information is lost-- C has a type system but it is compile time only. Basically, string data like `%f` and the C type system are completely foreign concepts that never communicate. So try to imagine your program without any string data like `%f`. How could the compiler know to run the compile-time int->float conversion?

Again, this only applies to variadic functions, not regular function calls. Ordinary function calls exhibit type-handling that is similar to most modern languages. Variadic functions, on the other hand, are unique to C. Similar to `void *` pointers, they should be considered dangerous and used with care.

EDIT:
`float x = 23;` results in a promotion because the language has a functional type system (although types are ONLY known at compile time). The type system just doesn't work inside variadic function arguments, i.e. the inputs to `printf`.

Comment: then why does it not treat the 23 as 23.00 as other languages like Java do??

Comment: because the type information is not persisted into the `printf` implementation. This broken behavior is specific to variadic functions such as `printf`. Regular function calls don't have this problem. `printf` receives `va_list` which is untyped binary, it cannot interpret the memory unless the format specifier, %f, tells it what it is.

Comment: @coder12345: Because given `printf("%f", 23)`, the compiler doesn't know that the expected type is `double`. The format string doesn't have to be known at compile time; it could be `char *format = "%f"; printf(format, 23)`. Bottom line: C is not other languages.

Comment: @coder12345 mainly because C holds varargs differently

Comment: "_broken_" is an arguable term. ;)

Comment: @Qix : Yeah, it follows the spec, but the whole `va_list` system is pretty hard to defend as a good design by modern standards ;). You can't even tell when the list ends unless you make sure it's terminated or you have another way to tell when you're done reading data. It did enable a convenient looking syntax at the time though.

Comment: @VoidStar oh for sure; by modern standards, most languages look like crap. `va_list` and all of its... beauty has always annoyed me a bit.

Comment: The type double is expected by `printf`, not the compiler, so the compiler can't know how it should promote the value and simply follow default promotion

Comment: @Qix  We all look _beautiful_ in our 20s.  C is 43+ and has many children who now look beautiful.  We and they will age too.